# Is this some "Repetitive Error Loop in C?"

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm witnessing some trouble compiling this code wherein you may see a nice if-else statement in practice but as soon as I compile the code, I get a **"statement missing"** error in the compiler to basically terminate the **"if"** statement before the highlighted parenthesis, which is weird but when I perform it, the compiler starts to show another error stating a **"misplaced else"** statement now.

What is the actual error in here and how should I proceed?

```
///////////////////// Input Code ////////////////////

int getcount()
{int count=0;
FILE*fp;
fp=fopen("counter.DAT","rb");
```

```
    If(fp==NULL)
  
    *{
    
    fp=fopen("counter.DAT","wb");
    count=2;
       
    If(fp==NULL)
     {
      printf("\nErorr");
      getch();
      exit(0);
     }
        
    fwrite(&count,sizeof(int),1,fp);
    count=1;
    }
    
    else
    {
    
    fread(&count,sizeof(int),1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("counter.DAT","wb");

    If(fp==NULL)
     {
      printf("\nErorr");
      getch();
      exit(0);
     }
       
    count++;
    fwrite(&count,sizeof(int),1,fp);
    count--;
    }
    
    while(count>2)
    {count=count-2;}
 
    fclose(fp);
    return count;}
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/7509065)

Comment: I have added very basic code-formatting to your code, but I am wary about making more edits, in case they change your question. Please consider looking through your post and removing unnecessary spaces. Also note that you can't use the `**` **bold** format inside code.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question so it is readable: indented correctly and  with { and } on their own line

Comment: And put your highlights in comments so the code in your question when compiled Without modification shows the exact error you see

Comment: And include #includes so your code is a [mre] if you don't know what a [mre] is, click on [mre] and read.

Answer (score 4):

Try a lower-case, "if"... I haven't tested it, but at first glance, that seems to be what's going on here.

Comment: It's a good answer! Normally, for users with >50 reputation, I would mildly suggest that this would be better as a comment, than as an answer. However, I appreciate that, *at the time of posting*, you didn't have that privilege.

Comment: The lower-case "if" happens to trigger syntax misexpression error!

Comment: @SlicKricE then you need to tell us the error.

Comment: @SlicKricE: We never heard back from you. Did the lower-case i work for you eventually?